# Emulate Chrome using php to capture html code from a page

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I am trying to automate scraping Urls from a website.

The Start page is ** https://www.home.co.uk/search/agents/ **

When the source is viewed in Chrome a section of the page source shows all the hrefs

````
    <div id="homeco_v6_page_content" class="clearfix">
      <div id="homeco_v6_main">
                        
            <div class="homeco_content">
                <div class="homeco_content_header">
                    <h1>UK Estate Agents</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="homeco_content_main homeco_content_min_height">
                <p>There are 16,256 Estate Agents listed in the Home.co.uk Estate Agent Directory. Estate Agents that actively promote their clients' properties online are assigned an Estate Agent details page showing the Agent's location, contact details, membership of the The Property Ombudsman (TPOS) or National Association of Estate Agents (NAEA) and their online property advertising profile.</p>

<p>Estate Agents who have signed up to a Code of Practice under the <a href="https://www.tpos.co.uk/" target="_blank">TPOS</a> or <a href="http://www.naea.co.uk/" target="_blank">NAEA</a> offer greater peace of mind to their clients. Home sellers who wish to instruct an Estate Agent can <a href="/selling/agent_contact/free_valuation.htm">request a free market appraisal</a> from a recommended local Estate Agent.</p>

<p>See also: <a href="/guides/selling/estateagents.htm">Selling with an Estate Agent</a>, <a href="/selling/">Home Selling</a>, <a href="/letting_agents/">Letting Agents</a></p><p>To search for estate agents by name or in a particular town or postcode, enter the details into the boxes below and click on Search: </p><form action="/search/agents/" class="form form-labels-compact">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Agent Name:</label>
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" name="agent" value="" id="agent" class="input--large">
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location:</label>
        <div class="form-control">
            <input type="text" name="where" value="" id="where" class="input--large">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
    </div>
</form>
<p>You can also search for <a href="/search/agents/?postal_areas=1">Estate Agents by Postcode</a>.</p><h2 id="england" class="country-heading"><img src="https://www.home.co.uk/images/english_flag_small.gif" alt="england" width=34 height=20> England</h2><ul class="bullet-list columns-2 columns--regular">
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=beds">Estate Agents in Bedfordshire</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=berks">Estate Agents in Berkshire</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=bucks">Estate Agents in Buckinghamshire</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=cambs">Estate Agents in Cambridgeshire</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=cheshire">Estate Agents in Cheshire</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=cleveland">Estate Agents in Cleveland</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=cornwall">Estate Agents in Cornwall</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=cumbria">Estate Agents in Cumbria</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=derbys">Estate Agents in Derbyshire</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=devon">Estate Agents in Devon</a><br></li>
<li><a href="/search/agents/?county=dorset">Estate Agents in Dorset</a><br></li>```
````

BUT when I use PHP from a server to capture the source from the page as in this example using "file_get_contents"

```
<?php


$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "Accept-language: en\r\n" .
            "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
    ]
];

// DOCS: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
// DOCS: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
$file = file_get_contents('https://www.home.co.uk/search/agents/', false, $context);



echo $file;

?>
```

I get an Error that seems to load and errorForm DIV in the middle of the returned html showing an error in place of where the hrefs are being generated.

```
  <div id="homeco_v6_header">
        <div id="homeco_top_logo_left">
          <a href="/" target="_top"><img src="/images/v6/logo_square_sunflowers.jpg" width="88" height="94" alt="Home.co.uk" /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="homeco_top_banner"></div>
        <div id="homeco_top_logo_right">
          <a href="/" target="_top"><img src="/images/v6/logo_square_sunflowers.jpg" width="88" height="94" alt="Home.co.uk" /></a>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- end homeco_v6_header -->
        <!-- ENDHEADERCONTENT -->
        <div id="homeco_v6_page_content" class="clearfix">
          <div id="homeco_v6_main">

                        <div class="homeco_content">
                                <div class="homeco_content_header">
                                        <h1>Website Error</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="homeco_content_main homeco_content_min_height">
                                <div id="errorForm" style="display: none">

<table width="100%" cellPadding=2 cellSpacing=0 border=0>

        <p />
```

I have used various examples of code from StackOverflow articles that utilise wget &  curl from the command line and the results are the same - e.g.

> curl -o regions.txt -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Safari/537.36"     "https://www.home.co.uk/search/agents/"

This example from commandline curl still shows an error DIV in the middle of the saved file regions.txt

My hope is to recursively traverse the pages from -  https://www.home.co.uk/search/agents/

to  each link such as  https://www.home.co.uk/search/agents/?county=beds that are embedded in the page agents page

to the last level - https://www.home.co.uk/search/agents/results.htm?location=ampthill

to the scrape all the estate agent names, addresses and phone numbers

```
1.
Country Properties - 08720 453646*
1 Church Street,, Ampthill,, MK45 2PJ

2.
Indigo Residential - 01525 625059
101 Dunstable Street,, Ampthill,, MK45 2NG

3.
Orchards Estate Agents - 01525 625038
The Clock House, Bedford Street,, Ampthill,, MK45 2NB

4.
Town Country - Ampthill - 01525 204787
13 Church Street, Ampthill, MK45 2PL

5.
Urban & Rural - 08724 773549*
Ampthill, Bedfordshire, MK45 2LU
```

Comment: I tested the PHP code you gave and I do get the full HTML content of the page, including the links.

Comment: I just used a proxy - and think that their server must be blocking me after too many attempts at accessing. I am going to set up a HMA on my test Linux server and flip the external IP address to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have now discovered that the server I was trying to access was blocking my access to code and showing an report an error div instead of the results i was trying to scrape. So my solution was to use HMA scripts  to flip my server IP address if I encountered being blocked.   https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202721456-Recommended-Linux-CLI-OpenVPNOpenVPN-Client